# Does any one know if the PFD or ND or any other screen on an commercial aircraft work like a computer or something else?

Tags: commercial-aviation

Does any one know if the PFD or ND or any other screen on an commercial aircraft work like a computer or something else? Like does the screen work like a computer and read 0s and 1s like maybe for sensors for smoke it sends a particular amount of 0s and 1s to show on the screen there is a fire and have hard drives and graphic cards and all that stuff or do they work completely different?

Comment: They are essentially standard computers.  They frequently run a custom OS, but run on fairly mainstream processors, and are programmed with typical low-level programming languages.

Answer (score 2):

All multi-functional displays in modern avionics are just computers. Typically, they are only responsible for *presentation* of the supplied information, but may do some processing: for example, display certain alerts in the right conditions. Also, they manage some of the <s>user</s> pilot input and mode switching.

[image: G1000 PFD diagnostics page]
<sup>G1000 PFD diagnostics page</sup>

Nearly all the data comes in on digital bus(es), in aviation most commonly [ARINC 429](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARINC_429) or even Ethernet with a custom protocol.

Bare sensors either have a dedicated microcontroller that converts the readings to a digital format, or are connected to a dedicated processing unit (also a specialised computer), such as ADC (Air Data Computer) which collects and processes all the air-related data (airspeed, altitude, temperature, etc.)

Even then, typically, this semi-processed data don't go to displays directly. All the sensor data are collected by a sort of integration unit (e.g. GIA for Garmin systems), which does most of the processing and decision making. Then, the necessary information is relayed to the displays.

Comment: Zeus so the Airbus ECAM system would be equivalent to what you said?

Comment: @GaryZenger, I'm not intimately familiar with it, but basically yes; my understanding is that ECAM is conceptually equivalent to GIA that I mentioned.